# How to do curve like animation in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know that the title is not very specific, i'm extremely sorry for that, actually I couldn't think a better title than it.

Now coming to my design, Below is the desired result. I want to do it with an CURVED like animation (just like the image). **But the problem is its going like a straight diagonal line not curved one.**

`_startCoin` function is called whenever i click a button and then animation is happening

[image: attachedimage]

And here is my code

```
const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);
const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);

export default class demoScreen extends Component {

state = {
    ready: false,
    CoinAdd: new Animated.Value(0),
};

_startCoin = () => {
    return Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.state.CoinAdd, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1500,
        useNativeDriver: true
      })
    ]).start();
 };

render() {
    let { CoinAdd } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn2} onPress={() => this._startCoin()}>
      <Text style={styles.textBtn}>Start Coin</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <Animated.View style={{
               transform: [
               {
                 translateY: CoinAdd.interpolate({
                 inputRange: [0, 1],
                 outputRange: [0, -((screenHeight/2)-50)]
                })
               },
               {
                 translateX: CoinAdd.interpolate({
                 inputRange: [0, 1],
                 outputRange: [0, -((screenWidth/2))]
               })
               }
               ],
               borderRadius: 12,
               justifyContent: "center",
               alignItems: 'center',
               zIndex: 2
              }}
            >
<Image style={{position: "absolute",  height: 30, width: 30, right: 0}} source={require('../../assets/coin.png')} />

</Animated.View>

);
}
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you